# How to combine two components using allOf in openapi yaml specification?

Tags: java, yaml, openapi, codegen

I try to generate java model classes from yaml specification using openapi-generator-maven-plugin:3.3.4.
In one component I have allOf parameter trying to combine two different components by their refs. It goes like:

`Flight:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightReference'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightItem'`

What I got is Flight class which extends FlightReference, and FlightItem is not included in model at all. AFAIK in swagger-codegen-maven-plugin all properties from both classes was placed in class Flight, and current plugin introduces polymorphism instead, missing fields from second component.

Is there a way to create class which combines all parameters from two other components as in swagger 2.0 plugin?

Comment: Have you tried writing two `allOf` like  `Flight:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightReference'
   allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightItem'`

Comment: @SudhirOjha thanks! If we put another allOf keyword in an array then it also extends first class but includes fields from second. And going forward I change your clue a little, and if we make something like this: `Flight:
      allOf:
        - allOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightItem' then 
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/FlightReference'` then properties from both classes are copied into target. So it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.3.4 was released a while ago. Please upgrade to the latest stable version v4.2.3, which should solve the problem for you in terms of how `allOf` is handled.

Comment: you're right, it seems like 4.2.3 would work, thanks!

Comment: FYI. We just released 4.3.0: https://twitter.com/oas_generator/status/1243455743937789952